# Delete unused branch (local and remote) which is already merged with master

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I did some svn to git migration. Some branches are migrated which I don't need anymore. They are already merged with my master so that's fine:

```
on master branch
# git branch --contains trunk@1009
* master
```

When I perform `git branch -a` on my real gitrepo I see

```
* master
  test
  uat
  trunk@1009
  remotes/svn/uat
  remotes/svn/test
  remotes/svn/trunk
  remotes/svn/trunk@1009
```

What's the difference between `trunk@1009` and `remotes/svn/trunk@1009`?
When I perform the same on my git clone (local)

```
git branch -a
* master
  uat
  test
  remotes/origin/trunk@1009
  ...
```

Now is my question. What's the right way to delete the branch trunk@1009 (local and remote?) from my git server. I want to delete the branch before people start cloning so they don't see anything of that branch in their local clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between trunk@1009 and remotes/svn/trunk@1009

`trunk@1009` is your local branch and `remotes/svn/trunk@1009` is your remote branch.

Delete local `trunk@1009` branch

```
$ git branch -D trunk@1009
```

Delete remote `trunk@1009` branch

```
$ git push origin :trunk@1009
```

Cleanup remote deleted branch

```
$ git remote prune origin

$ git fetch               # fetch the remote
$ git branch -a           # see all branches
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not understand why a local branch exists on my git-server and on my local repo I only see the remote branch?

Comment: I guess you push your local branch to remote so, `trunk@1009` exists in your remote branch list. `git branch -a` shows both local & remote branch. The branch start with `remotes/svn/` is your remote branch and others are local branch.

Comment: so you can have local branches on your git server (not the clone) itself?

Comment: `git branch` shows local branches and `git branch -r` shows only remote branches

Comment: If you clone a fresh copy then you will see only remote branches. Then if you create a new branch locally you will see that branch in local branch lists.

Comment: I think I understand everything except one thing: a remote branch (on your clone) is on the git server a remote branch AND a local branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144914/discussion-between-sajib-khan-and-dencowboy).